# How to assign javascript variables value to javascript array?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have my values stored in javascript variables now,i want to assign those values to javascript array. Here i am posting the image for same

[image: img]

I want my array to be intialized with these variables values,since values in variables are generated dynamicaly, the are not static values.values in given variables are generated at run time, so i cant pre-intialze the array with the values, like i have done in the picture.

Comment: If I understand it right, the last commented green line in image is doing the same. It creates an array with variable values

Comment: Why include your code as an image? Besides that, it is a bit hard to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @HaseebAsif: but the commented line doesnt work the way it should.

Comment: What's the issue with that, any error or how you want it to be? Check this  
https://jsfiddle.net/haseeb1431/5hdLxskd/1/

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt: all my code is very long and un-nessary for all stackoverflow friends. rest of my code is working the way it should. I am just stuck how can i intialize the array dynamicaly. values stored in ts2,ts3... and so on are dynamicaly generated at run time in javascript function, i want my array to be intialized with those values..so to make my question appear simple i have intialized variables with somw values and assign same to array.

Comment: @HaseebAsif: Issue is i split the array on (,) . but i dont get required result... plz check here http://jsfiddle.net/usmanrather/s1xtcvhp/

Comment: You don't need to split it. Splitting turns a string into an array, but you'll already have an array, so you can just skip that step. :)

Comment: you have to user wrappers

Comment: I have updated the code : http://jsfiddle.net/haseeb1431/s1xtcvhp/2/

Comment: @JeremyBanks: thats true. but i have to nessesarily pass them as three diffrent cordinates. so i guess cordinates for polygon must be passed as three difrrent points which are stored in single array.

Comment: @HaseebAsif. Thanks for the edit, but i cant have now polygon on the map, since you erased that part, where intial values from array were taken as starting point for the polygon

Comment: bro my bad, I just deleted accidentally that part try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/haseeb1431/s1xtcvhp/4/

Comment: @HaseebAsif: sorry bro your code doesnt work. neither it shows map nor it creates polygon over that.

Comment: array is being built with coordinates accordingly, I am not sure what's going on in your code, I think you need to push your polygon to the map as well. Can you paste your complete code?

Comment: @HaseebAsif here is the complete working code. make the changes as we have discussed above http://jsfiddle.net/usmanrather/s1xtcvhp/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having

```
var latlongs = boundary.split(",");
```

You can just write

```
var latlongs = boundary;
```

Since the boundary is a properly initialized array and not a string (as you've commented out a line above)

**Edit**

This [*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/67ojrc3q/) should be what you were asking for.
There's many different ways to cast numbers into strings and then concatenate those to one string. Since you already had the `boundary` array, I thought it would be the simplest to just use `.join()` on that.

**Edit #2**

So, your code had a lot of unnecessary `}` closing brackets (line 108, 109, etc)
You ought to check your browser's console, for it had the error lines right there.

As for the string that we're trying to create, you never mentioned they had to be pairs of coordinates in the format of '1 2, 3 4, 5 6'

```
var boundary = [ts2 + ' ' + ts3, ts4 + ' ' + ts5, ts6 + ' ' + ts7];
boundary = boundary.join();
```

with removing the closing brackets, this works for me
- [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOsbD.jpg)

And your [full code](http://pastebin.com/hgKiz6h2) reworked.

Comment: line i have commented above is exactly what i require but dynamicaly, thats is i dont want my array to be intialized with static values, i want them intialized at run time.

Comment: the line  `var array = [ts1,ts2,ts3,ts4,ts5,ts6];`   does create an array with dynamic values, so I'm a bit confused by your needs.

Comment: please check here http://jsfiddle.net/usmanrather/s1xtcvhp/  (line in the code commented does exactly what i want,but with static values, i.e only assigned in the array, yet i want my array should be dynamicaly intialized. ) thats what i want exactly

Comment: To start things off, the line commented is not an array. Secondly, what do you think a 'dynamically' initialized array is, if not your initialization of `boundary` at the moment?

Comment: Sorry and thanks for pointing it out. I can be more clear now. var boundary is a string i want dynamicaly store string values in that, how can i?

Comment: I see : ) Is this what you're looking for?  [*Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/67ojrc3q/)

Comment: I put your code for check, but doesnt provide required result.

Comment: What is the required result and how does it differ from the string we create in my last fiddle?

Comment: Required result is: Create Google map with polygon over it,which is dynamicaly created by user. here is the complete code. http://jsfiddle.net/usmanrather/s1xtcvhp/5/

Comment: I meant the required result for this question. How would the dynamically created string have to differ?

Comment: I've edited my answer once more. Please see if this works for you.. it did for me.

Comment: many many thanks... You resolved my problem.. I am thankful to you. can we be friends on fb. my id is usman_rather@yahoo.co.in